# More Mockito RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS woes

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I recently read and used some examples as seen in the GitHub Repo linked below, which is for extending the basic Spring Boot error objects. I am attempting to write some tests for the `ApiError.java` class, and in particular #addValidationErrors

https://github.com/brunocleite/spring-boot-exception-handling/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springbootexceptionhandling/ApiError.java

The basic issue is that I've not found a way to get the chaining of the methods to return values to work.  My test at this point looks something like this...

```
@Test
public void addValidationErrors() {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.OK);
    ConstraintViolation mockViolation = Mockito.mock(ConstraintViolation.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Mockito.when(mockViolation.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()).thenReturn("MyBeanName");
...
```

At this point the test dies with a `NullPointerException` on the line which invokes the `Mockito.when` method.  I've tried different runner classes (Mockito, JUnit4 and even PowerMock) along with various annotation combinations such as `@PrepareForTest` and declaring the mockViolation outside the test under a `@Mock`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, but your specific problem here is that `getRootBeanClass` returns a `Class`, and Mockito *can't mock final classes*. Under the hood, when you ask to mock a class, Mockito generates a subclass that (effectively) overrides all methods and redirects them to Mockito control. This override mechanism is why you'll have trouble mocking `final` methods, as well as `final` classes like `java.lang.Class`.

Though you might be able to get this done with PowerMock, it's inadvisable, as in [Johan Haleby's post from powermock@googlegroups.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/hDdhthYZrqE) in 2011:

> I don't think there's a possibility to mock Class because that will mess up a lot of PowerMock internal stuff. You can how ever mock the "getClass()" method of Objects if you set MockGateway.MOCK_GET_CLASS_METHOD = true.
>
> I would strongly advice [sic] against mocking Class or getClass method though. Try to verify it in some other way.

Because you're only concerned about making `getSimpleName` return a predictable value, consider creating a new class ("MyBean") and setting `getRootBeanClass()` to return it. It'll be very easy to mock a return value on an interface, and you'll get the same kind of simple name return value you're looking to use.